# Creating objects whose names are stored in the configuration file

Tags: python, json, config

I'm trying to create a program that, depending on the handlers registered in the configuration file, will create objects for passing them to a method of another class.

I have a configuration file with a set of names of certain handlers that should be passed to the method of my application.
This is config.json file:

```
{
    "handlers": [
        "handler1",
        "handler2"
    ]
}
```

How to select the necessary objects that are stored in the config?

The code below shows that to register objects, you need to save them in a list.
What are the best practices for solving this problem?

```py
class Observer:
    #some code

class BaseHandler:
    #some code

class Handler1(BaseHandler):
    #some code

class Handler2(BaseHandler):
    #some code

class Handler3(BaseHandler):
    #some code

handler1 = Handler1()
handler2 = Handler2()
handler3 = Handler3()
handlers = [handler1, handler2, handler3]

observer = Observer()
observer.method_for_handling(handlers)
```

Comment: What establishes the mapping be the json file strings and class names? i.e. `"handler1"` ⇒ `Handler1`. When does the object registration occur and when is the json file being read/used?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have file
`main.py`

```
class Observer:
  def __init__(self, handlers):
    self.handlers = handlers

  def event(self):
    for handler in self.handlers:
      handler.event()

class BaseHandler:
  pass

class Handler1(BaseHandler):
  def event(self):
    print("Handler1")

class Handler2(BaseHandler):
  def event(self):
    print("Handler2")

class Handler3(BaseHandler):
  def event(self):
    print("Handler3")
```

Now you have your `config.json` file with **valid** names and it's a valid JSON.

```
{"handlers": ["Handler1", "Handler2"]}
```

Then to load it you can do something like this:
`configure.py`

```
import observers
import json

with open("config.json", "r") as fp:
  config = json.loads(fp.read())

handlers = [getattr(observers, handler_name)() for handler_name in config['handlers']]
# At this point handlers are ready to be used so u can write any custom logic u want.
ob = observers.Observer(handlers)
ob.event()
```

Result:

```
Handler1
Handler2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) depending on what you need and what you want along with your JSON converted into valid python dict like this example:

```
import json


my_json = '''{
    "handlers": [
        "Handler1",
        "Handler2"
    ]
}'''


class Observer:
    def method_for_handling(self, handlers):
        for handler in handlers:
            try:
                globals()[handler]()
            except KeyError:
                print('Handler not supported! : ', handler)


class BaseHandler:
    def event(self):
        print('Base Handler')


class Handler1(BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Init in handler 1')

    def event(self):
        print('Base Handler1')


class Handler2(BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Init in handler 2')

    def event(self):
        print('Base Handler2')


conf = json.loads(my_json)
observer = Observer()
observer.method_for_handling(conf['handlers'])
```

Output:

```
Init in handler 1
Init in handler 2
```

And you can push this example further and you can access directly to the methods by adding them in the JSON attributes. Here is an example:

```
# See here how we defined the first handler
my_json = '''{
    "handlers": [
        "Handler1.event",
        "Handler2"
    ]
}'''

class Observer:
    def method_for_handling(self, handlers):
        for handler in handlers:
            try:
                if '.' in handler:
                    # Here i'm assuming that we'll use only one method
                    # of the handler class. You can improve it to use
                    # chained methods if you want
                    _handler, *_, func = handler.partition('.')
                    main = globals()[_handler]()
                    getattr(main, func)()
                else:
                    globals()[handler]()
            except KeyError:
                print('Handler not supported! : ', handler)
```

So, if you modify the actual `method_for_handling` you'll have an output:

```
Init in handler 1
Base Handler1
Init in handler 2
```

So, here we can see that, both, the method `event` of the class `BaseHandler1` were executed.